# Complex Euclidean Geometry Question

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let w be the incircle of a fixed equilateral triangle ABC. Let l be a variable line that is tangent to w and meets the interior of segments AC and BC at P and Q, respectively. A point R is chosen such that PR = PA and QR = QB. Find all locations of the point R over all choices of l.

So I drew the diagram, and tried angle chasing, and noted that ARMB is cyclic, where M is the midpoint of BC, but from there, I really didn't know what to do. Please provide some hints, but full proofs would be even better. I really need a full proof, it is kinda urgent. Thank You[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109623/discussion-on-question-by-randomkid-complex-euclidean-geometry-question).

Comment: Please restore my comment. It had nothing to do with any "extended discussion". Even more importantly, please restore some of Blue's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trace of my GeoGebra sketch for the case with $|PA|=|PR|$ and $|QB|=|QR|$ (showing two instances of $R$ that trace separate arcs of the complete curve).

[image]

For an origin-centered incircle of radius $r$, as shown, the locus is a [limaçon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on)-like curve with equation

$$(x^2+y^2-2r^2)^2 = 4 r^3 (4y+5r) \tag{1}$$

---

For the case with $|AR|=|PR|$ and $|BR|=|QR|$ ...

[image]

The locus is a hyperbola with equation

$$- x^2 + 3 y^2 + 8 r y + 4 r^2  = 0 \tag{2}$$

---

Neither of these results is particularly "easy" to derive. I got them via coordinate-bashing in *Mathematica*. It's possible that the hyperbola follows from a nice geometric argument, but OP has stated that the conditions of the limaçon-like curve are in play. As one might expect, the limaçon-like curve is the trickier of the two, requiring a bit of parametric problem-solving, yet OP suggests that the problem shouldn't be that hard. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, just a figure to illustrate my comment. It's Community Wiki, so feel free to add stuff. (Preferably not insults, RandomKid!) $\ \ddot\smile$

[image]

In the coordinate system from Blue's answer, when the tangent $l$ meets the incircle $\omega$ at $K,$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
A = (-\sqrt3, -1), & B = (\sqrt3, -1), & E = (0, -1), &
C = (0, 2), & K = (0, 1), \\
P = \left(-\frac1{\sqrt3}, 1\right), & Q = \left(\frac1{\sqrt3}, 1\right), &
L = (-\sqrt7, 1), & M = (\sqrt7, 1), & R = (0, 1 + \sqrt5).
\end{array}
$$
I've taken the radius of the incircle as the unit of measurement. The points $A, B, L, M, R$ all lie on the true locus, as described by Blue's equation (1) with $r = 1$:
$$
(x^2 + y^2 - 2)^2 = 4(4y + 5).
$$
The equation of the elliptical arc $BMRLA$ that seems to approximate the true locus closely is:
$$
\left(\frac{15 + 4\sqrt5}{29}\right)x^2 +
\left(y - \frac{15 + 4\sqrt5}{29}\right)^2 =
\left(\frac{14 + 25\sqrt5}{29}\right)^2.
$$
(I don't know if this can be simplified, nor do I know why the approximation seems so close.)